# Can't build new .deb package

Tags: dpkg, deb, bazaar, 14.10

I'm trying to create a new .deb package, but the build fails with the following output:

```
dpkg-genchanges: error: binary build with no binary artifacts found; cannot distribute
dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-genchanges gave error exit status 2
debuild: fatal error at line 1364:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc failed
bzr: ERROR: The build failed.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to this bug report: [bugs.debian.org #831939](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=831939)

They fixed with following patch:

```
--- a/debian/rules
+++ b/debian/rules
@@ -31,12 +31,12 @@ install: build
    # rename jailer.pl to jailer
    mv `pwd`/debian/jailer/usr/sbin/jailer.pl `pwd`/debian/jailer/usr/sbin/jailer
 
-# Build architecture-independent files here.
-binary-indep: build install
+# Build architecture-dependent files here.
+binary-arch:
 # We have nothing to do by default.
 
-# Build architecture-dependent files here.
-binary-arch: build install
+# Build architecture-independent files here.
+binary-indep: build install
    dh_testdir
    dh_testroot
 #  dh_installdebconf
```

So, depending on the used target tags in rules file, `dpkg-buildpackage` will run specific checks automatically.

Full details found in: [debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-source.html#s-debianrules](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-source.html#s-debianrules)